# How to replicate google analytics segment in google BigQuery?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, segment

Does one of you replicate google analytics segment & specially advanced segments with sequences conditions within Google BigQuery?

I mean for instance:

users who had for instance a clientid which is either 1234555.6666 or 1234665.6644 or 12345855.6256 ? and page ABC and after followed by page YYYVV

I did find it right now within the questions on stack?

Example of advanced segment to create in bigqueryenter image description here[enter image description here]1 enter image description here enter image description here

Here's an example of my query

```sql
#standard sql

select
  MAX (hits.hitNumber) as max_hitnumber,
  fullvisitorid AS fullvisitorid,
  visitid AS visitid,
  clientId as clientId,
  date as date,
  hits.hour AS hit_hour,
  hits.minute AS hit_minute,
  hits.isExit AS hit_isExit,
  hits.type AS hit_type,
  (SELECT MAX(IF(index=4, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS type_de_la_page,
  (SELECT MAX(IF(index=5, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS titre_de_la_page, 
  (SELECT MAX(IF(index=6, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS univers_affichage
FROM `dataset.ga_sessions_*`, UNNEST(hits) as hits
WHERE  
   _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN 'XX' AND 'YY'
  AND
  clientId IN ('1216107517.1566907413','2133916944.1568016396','191276059.1563523657','2099333168.1568989130','40560158.1568714387','1148175150.1568740892','2006464416.1569333485')
 AND
  ((SELECT MAX(IF(index=10, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) = "prod")
 AND
  hits.type="PAGE"
 AND 
    (SELECT MAX(IF(index=4, value, NULL)) FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) ="home")

GROUP BY
  fullvisitorid,
  visitid,
  clientId,
  date,
  hit_hour,
  hit_minute,
  hit_type,
  type_de_la_page,
  titre_de_la_page,
  univers_affichage,
  hit_isExit
```

But don't know to add some regex conditions in my query for my google analytics custom dimension + also i don't know how to deal in google bigquery for adding in my query the element like in my google analytics segment is followed by.

Comment: Miss image, I read "Example of advanced segment to create in bigqueryenter image description here[enter image description here]1 enter image description here enter image description here"

Comment: Would it help if you used the REGEXP_CONTAINS function? See here for details: [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_contains)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; i will look at it thanks